# How to create and push an object in to firebase array?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My current logic is the following creating adding a document with a user id in to users collection, and push the first object, then on the second call I want to be able to update the excising array with a new object.

```js
const docRef = doc(db, 'user', _authContext.currentUser.uid);
const payload = { items: [{item1 : 1}] };
await setDoc(docRef, payload);


// New array after update (second call of the function)
items: [{item1 : 1}, {item2 : 2}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for:

```
await updateDoc(docRef, { items: arrayUnion({ item2: 2 }) });
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on [adding items to an array](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array).

Comment: would it work ,if the doc is not there to begin with ?

Comment: I want to be able to create on the fly since the array will be dependent on a user, and I could have 1000 , for example, since I don't have access to the document id before creating the document and I want to related to users form authentication

Comment: If the doc may not exist yet, you'll need to use [`setDoc` and provide merge options](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document).